# PHP 5.4 check both Password Verify

Tags: php, cryptography

I have PHP version 5.4 on my PC so therefore I can't use `password_hash()` and I used `crypt()` instead.

But the next problem is how to verify passwords if they match?

The PHP documentation said that if you use `crypt()` the best way to use as password versifier is `hash_equals()` but only PHP 5.5.

I always get:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function hash_equals() in...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have mentioned php 5.4 doesn't have this functions yet, so you have two options to make use of this very useful functions:

The better way:

Update to php 5.5/5.6 and use the then native library

If that's not possible:

You can use this library:

https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat

The library provides forward compatibility with the password_* functions being worked on for PHP 5.5.

Answer (score 2):

You could just compare them both like this:

```
<?php 
$the_password= crypt('12345', 'aasddas');
$user_entered_pass='125';
if(crypt($user_entered_pass,'aasddas') == $the_password){
    echo "right";
}else{
    echo "wrong";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that is what [password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) is for, so use it.

> The PHP documentation said that if you use `crypt()` the best way to use as password versifier is `hash_equals()` but only PHP 5.5.

1. If you're following sane advice, then you're not using `crypt()`, you're using `password_hash()` with [`password_verify()`](https://secure.php.net/password_verify).
2. `hash_equals()` was added in PHP 5.6, not 5.5.